# List of Posts and Categories

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, categories

I have a custom taxonomy of Species and a custom post type of Animals. I would like to display them in a tree view like so:

### All Animals

- **Fish (taxonomy term)**

  - Shark (Custom Post Type)
  - Sun Fish
- **Mammals**

  - Monkey
  - Zebra

Each item in the list would be linked to its respective place. So the custom post types link to the animal and the taxonomy terms go to the taxonomy page. I'm aware of ways for WordPress to list categories, but I would also like the posts grouped under each category (custom taxonomy) as well.

Comment: I tried a few plugins and also tried listing the categories and looping through the posts. It seemed a little too involved for what I can do.

So I list out the terms, but I'm not sure how to check for posts of that type under the term and list them and move on to the next and repeat.

Comment: Assuming that you're using something like [`get_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) to fetch your list of custom categories:  As you loop through your categories, you can grab all the posts in that category using `get_posts()` ([see here for an example of getting all posts in a given custom taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts#Taxonomy_Parameters)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hey @neoian - what you need is a 2 step process.**

1. Loop the categories / terms
2. Then inside each category / term, query the posts.

.

```
$terms = get_terms("some_taxonomy");
$count = count($terms);

if ( $count > 0 ){
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

    $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'some_taxonomy' );

        echo '<h4 class="termTitle"><a href="'.$term_link.'">' . $term->name . '</a></h4>';
        $loop = new WP_Query( array( 
            'post_type' => 'some_postype',
            'posts_per_page' => 1000,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'some_taxonomy',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $term->term_id
                )
            )
        ));

        // the loop
        echo '<ul>';
        while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

            // get posts inside term
            $postID     = $loop->post->ID;
            $postTitle  = $loop->post->post_title;

            echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';

        endwhile;
        // reset $post so that the rest of the template is in the original context
        wp_reset_postdata();
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

**remember to:**
change "some_taxonomy" to the desired taxonomy and
'some_postype' to your custom post type...